# Multiple scenes on unity breaks everything

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine

I imported a main menu scene from unity and after dragging the prefab into the scene I realized everything was missing. My hierarchy was the same and everything was in place but none of the meshes would render. The main menu prefab has a camera in it so I changed the depth to be below to no avail. Ive been talking with the creator of the asset and he says its a glitch with unity, something to do with additive loading. Ive been trying to fix it for like a week now and barely anything has changed.

Comment: This question is off topic as it is about game development.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tag(s) you included. You are asking an off-topic question. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Should have been moved to Game Development Stack Exchange?

Comment: Imported from where? how? Do the meshes actually exist in the Assets folder?  Do they have content (file size > 0)?  A screen-shot of the hierarchy and scene window would be ideal!